# D3 color change on mouseover using classed("active",true)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, onmouseover, heatmap

I'm new to js and D3.  I've generated a heatmap of-sorts and would like to change the color of a tile using D3's on.mouseover.  I'm able to change the color explicitly but want to use a CSS active rule.  Probably something simple to fix.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  The full code is below.

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>MJ-Heatmap</title>
<header>
<H1>Country By District_Port_Nme Heatmap</H1>
<p></p>
</header>   
<style>
body {
font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.label {
font-weight: bold;
}
.tile {
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
fill: none;
stroke: #000;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
<!-- CSS active state not working -- >
.tile active {
fill: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var buckets = [
{country:"Brazil", distrinct_port_nme:"Baltimore, Maryland", sum_teu: 2, sum_weight: 18585, count_shipments: 1}, 
{country:"Colombia", distrinct_port_nme:"Baltimore, Maryland", sum_teu:28, sum_weight:258028, count_shipments:11}, 
{country:"Brazil", distrinct_port_nme:"Chicago, Illinois", sum_teu: 2, sum_weight: 18585, count_shipments: 1}, 
{country:"Colombia", distrinct_port_nme:"Houston, Texas", sum_teu:14, sum_weight: 95995, count_shipments: 7}, 
{country:"Brazil", distrinct_port_nme:"Long Beach, California", sum_teu: 2, sum_weight: 18584, count_shipments: 1}, 
{country:"China", distrinct_port_nme:"Long Beach, California", sum_teu: 2, sum_weight: 19180, count_shipments: 1}, 
{country:"Colombia", distrinct_port_nme:"Long Beach, California", sum_teu:12, sum_weight:117873, count_shipments: 6}, 
{country:"Singapore", distrinct_port_nme:"Long Beach, California", sum_teu: 6, sum_weight: 77176, count_shipments: 4}, 
{country:"Belgium", distrinct_port_nme:"Los Angeles, California", sum_teu: 2, sum_weight: 17780, count_shipments: 1}, 
{country:"Brazil", distrinct_port_nme:"Los Angeles, California", sum_teu: 2, sum_weight: 18584, count_shipments: 1}, 
{country:"Colombia", distrinct_port_nme:"Los Angeles, California", sum_teu: 7, sum_weight: 52046, count_shipments: 5}, 
{country:"Hong Kong", distrinct_port_nme:"Los Angeles, California", sum_teu: 2, sum_weight: 19180, count_shipments: 1}, 
{country:"India", distrinct_port_nme:"Los Angeles, California", sum_teu:48, sum_weight:460563, count_shipments:24}, 
{country:"Singapore", distrinct_port_nme:"Los Angeles, California", sum_teu:12, sum_weight:115384, count_shipments: 6}, 
{country:"Brazil", distrinct_port_nme:"New York, New York", sum_teu: 4, sum_weight: 27032, count_shipments: 2}, 
{country:"Colombia", distrinct_port_nme:"New York, New York", sum_teu: 8, sum_weight: 42885, count_shipments: 4}, 
{country:"India", distrinct_port_nme:"New York, New York", sum_teu:14, sum_weight:129116, count_shipments: 7}, 
{country:"Singapore", distrinct_port_nme:"New York, New York", sum_teu:42, sum_weight:560628, count_shipments:27}, 
{country:"Brazil", distrinct_port_nme:"Newark, New Jersey", sum_teu: 2, sum_weight: 18584, count_shipments: 1}, 
{country:"Colombia", distrinct_port_nme:"Newark, New Jersey", sum_teu:83, sum_weight:785372, count_shipments:42}, 
{country:"India", distrinct_port_nme:"Newark, New Jersey", sum_teu:62, sum_weight:587654, count_shipments:31}, 
{country:"Brazil", distrinct_port_nme:"Norfolk, Virginia", sum_teu: 8, sum_weight: 33622, count_shipments: 4}, 
{country:"India", distrinct_port_nme:"Norfolk, Virginia", sum_teu: 2, sum_weight: 17780, count_shipments: 1}, 
{country:"Brazil", distrinct_port_nme:"Philadelphia, Pennsylvania", sum_teu: 2, sum_weight: 20160, count_shipments: 1}
];
// margins
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 100, left_padding: 100},
width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
// axes and color scale
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeBands([0, width], .2),
y = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeBands([height,0], .2),
z = d3.scale.linear().range(["lightgrey", "steelblue"]);
var xStep = .5,
yStep = 50;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + margin.top + ")");
// Compute the scale domains.
x.domain(buckets.map(function(d){return d.country}));
y.domain(buckets.map(function(d){return d.distrinct_port_nme}));
z.domain([0, d3.max(buckets.map(function(d){return d.count_shipments}))]);
// Display the tiles for each bucket.
svg.selectAll(".tile")
.data(buckets)
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("class", "tile")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.country) + margin.left+margin.left_padding; })
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.distrinct_port_nme); })
.attr("width",x.rangeBand())
.attr("height",y.rangeBand())
.style("stroke","goldenrod")
.style("fill", function(d) { return z(d.count_shipments); })
.on("mouseover", function() { d3.select(this).classed("active", true ) })       // classed("active",boolean) not working
.on("mouseout",  function() { d3.select(this).classed("active", false) });
//  .on("mouseover", function() { d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");});    // this change work fine
//  .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");});           // this change work fine
svg.selectAll("text")
.data(buckets)
.enter().append("text")
.text("text")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.country) + margin.left + margin.left_padding + x.rangeBand()/2; })
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.distrinct_port_nme) + y.rangeBand()/2; })
.attr("dx",0)
.attr("dy",".35em")
.attr("text-anchor","middle")
.style("fill","black").attr("font-size","14").attr("font-weight","Bold")
.text( function(d) { return d.count_shipments; });
// Add a legend for the color values.
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
.data(z.ticks(6).slice(1).reverse())
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "legend")
.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + 0 + "," + (10 + i * 20) + ")"; });
legend.append("rect")
.attr("width", 20)
.attr("height", 20)
.style("fill", z);
legend.append("text")
.attr("x", 26)
.attr("y", 10)
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.text(String);
svg.append("text")
.attr("class", "label")
.attr("x", 0)
.attr("y", 0)
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.text("count_shipments");
// Add an x-axis with label.
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate("+ (margin.left+margin.left_padding) + "," + height + ")")
.attr("text_anchor", "top")
.call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"))
.append("text")
.attr("class", "label")
.attr("x", width-10)
.attr("y", -5)
.attr("text-anchor", "end")
.text("Country");
// Add a y-axis with label.
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.attr("transform", "translate("+ (margin.left+margin.left_padding) + "," + 0 + ")")
.attr("text-anchor","right")
.call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"))
.append("text")
.attr("class", "label")
.attr("y", 3)
.attr("dy", ".71em")
.attr("text-anchor", "end")
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
.text("distrinct_port_nme");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT**

First off, you were right that your CSS is slightly off.

```
.tile active {
  fill: red;
}
```

should be:

```
.tile.active {
  fill: red;
}
```

Then, sort of like I explained below, the fill you're applying to the element with

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return z(d.count_shipments); })
```

ends up taking precedence over the fill applied by the `active` class.

However, unlike what I initially suggested, you can work around it by simply swapping `style` with `attr`, so you need:

```
.attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.count_shipments); })
```

(probably should do this for stroke as well).

Here's an [updated, working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WEsUe/1/)

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

I suspect it works the way it should –– i.e. class "active" with its associated fill is being added/removed appropriately –– and you'd be able to verify this by right-clicking and inspecting the element in dev tools.

I think the real problem is that you're also setting a fill directly on the element (one line before your `.on("mouseover"...)` call), which ALWAYS overrides the fill applied by your class. Generally in CSS you could (not saying you should) use the `!important` keyword to force it to accept the fill applied by the class. But I'm pretty sure that won't work with SVG (as opposed to normal HTML elements).

So, I think your only option is:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return z(d.count_shipments); })
.on("mouseover", function() {
  d3.select(this)
    .attr('fill', '') // Un-sets the "explicit" fill (might need to be null instead of '')
    .classed("active", true ) // should then accept fill from CSS
})
.on("mouseout",  function() {
  d3.select(this)
    .classed("active", false)
    .attr('fill', function(d) { return z(d.count_shipments); }) // Re-sets the "explicit" fill
  });
```

Hope this works....

Comment: Thanks for help.  This didn't work either on my end.  I'm wondering if there's a newbie mistake in my CSS rule or how I reference it.

Comment: Thank God you answered this post ... It works for me ... you saved me ... thankyou thankyou :)