# Why isn't my AngularJS view updating?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

(Update: still haven't solved this.)

(Further update: I've had no further responses from anyone. Surely this must be solvable?)

I'm combining Angular and D3, which I think is causing some problems. My model is updating (console.log tells me so). And the view can see that vm.blueEV should be 0 at the beginning. But the view never updates.

I thought I needed to add `$scope.$apply()`, so I did, but it's not helping. Here's my relevant code. What am I missing?

// controller.js

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.blueEV = 0;

  vm.clickState = function(d, i, state) {

    $scope.$apply(function() {

      if (state.classList == "neutral") {
        d3.select(state)
            .classed({"neutral": false, "blue": true});
        vm.blueEV += d.ev;
        vm.unassignedEV -= d.ev;
      };

    });

  };

}]);
```

// directive.js

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      // val: '=',
      clickState: '&',
    },
    controller: 'myController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var vm = scope.vm;

      d3.json("public/us-states.json", function(json) {
        svg.selectAll("path")
            .data(json.features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("class", "neutral")
            .attr("id", "states")
            .on('click', function(d, i) {
              return vm.clickState(d, i, this);
            })
           [etc.]
```

Comment: I don't understand: d3.select(state)-> state is an object. As far as I know it should be a selector ('#mydiv') or something. And: Is your directive being called?

Comment: @user3791775 Yes, state is an object. The d3 is a map of US states. The directive is being called, and the class successfully changes when the state gets clicked.

Comment: I don't think you need $scope.apply because d3 is not in your Angular digest cycle. I don't know why it is not working though. You could try to create a non-angular script to test if it is working outside of angular.

Comment: @user3791775 Wouldn't I need $scope.$apply *because* d3 is not in the Angular digest cycle? Unless I'm misunderstanding how it works? (My first version of the app was non-Angular (using D3 and jQuery). Now I'm trying to use Angular instead of jQuery, and I'm running into this issue.)

Comment: Is the class being changed in your html if you inspect your svg?

Comment: @user3791775 Yup, it's being changed in the HTML.

Comment: maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709304/d3-color-change-on-mouseover-using-classedactive-true

Comment: Well, the color change is working fine. But I'm trying to update the variable ```vm.blueEV``` as well.

Comment: Can you create a complete reproducible example?  I assume `vm.blueEV` is data-bound in the view?

Comment: @Mark My app has a huge json file that I don't think can go in a jsfiddle. This is my original d3/jQuery app that I'm trying to rewrite with d3/Angular: http://electoral-college.herokuapp.com. Yes, ```vm.blueEV``` is data-bound as ```<body ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
<div class="dem-tally">
            Democrats: <div id="dems">{{ ctrl.blueEV }}</div>
          </div></body>```

Comment: @jslutzky, I don't have an answer for you, but here's some sample code that I think replicates your problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/hcBrsOz3MnsLR1alMfhc?p=preview

Comment: if your issue is related to the plunker created by @Mark, the reason that example isn't working is because the controller is not a singleton.  There are two declarations for the controller, one in the HTML (`ng-controller="myController as ctrl"`), the other in the directive (`controller: 'myController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',`.  The instance the directive declares is modifying the variable within itself, not the instance created by the HTML.

Comment: I haven't worked out a fully functional solution yet, but in general, you should not have controllers that represent page logic and directive logic at the same time.  You should instead have a controller for the overall page logic, and a separate controller for the directive logic.  Not only does this make it much more clear where the properties are bound, it also makes the directive portable, and not reliant on other features present on the page.

Comment: @Claies Good point about the two controller declarations. My code feels like a mess. It was easier to combine d3 with jQuery. I looked at a few tutorials about how to combine d3 with Angular and I was quite confused.

Comment: it's not that they don't play well together, it's more that angular has a *very specific* way of handling DOM changes, because it's intent is to take that job into the background so that you only have to mess with it when absolutely necessary.  The unfortunate side effect of this is that when it is necessary, you have to know much more about the steps the angular framework is going through.  jQuery, on the other hand, tries to make the DOM updates easier, but not abstract it away.